# What is the difference between a `text` field with a `keyword` analyzer and a `keyword field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
properties: {
  keyword: {
    type: "keyword"
    fields: {
      text: { type: "text", analyzer: "keyword" }
    }
  }
}
```

If I create an index with this mapping what is the difference between `keyword` and `keyword.text`?

Answer (score 1):

Both are same. Keyword type/analyzer -as per document accepts whatever text it is given and outputs the exact same text as a single term.

If intention is to do an exact match keyword type should be preferred. If you need to customise it (ex. case insensitive search) then custom analyzer can used to modify it.